# continuous extension at x=0

Tags: calculus

> The function $f(x) = (\arctan \left(\frac 1x\right))^2$ has a continuous extension at $x=0$ because $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)= \dfrac{\pi^2}4$.

I solved it using squeeze theorem.

I am trying to use the same method for $\arctan$ because: $\dfrac{-\pi}2 < \arcsin < \dfrac{\pi}2$ . Does it work?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: can i use squeeze theorem to check whether (arcsin(1/x))2 has continuous extension at x=0

Answer (score 1):

The arcsinus function is only defined for $ x\in [-1,1] $.

So, to the function $$x\mapsto \arcsin(\frac 1x)$$

is defined if
$$0<\frac 1x \le 1$$
or
$$-1\le \frac 1x <0$$

which is equivalent to
$$x\ge 1 \text{ or } x\le -1$$

this tells us, that the function $$x\mapsto (\arcsin(\frac 1x))^2$$

is not defined near $ 0 $, so, we cannot speak about
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\arcsin(\frac 1x))^2$$

Comment: is it the same for arccos?

Comment: @LamaBitar Yes. it is not defined near zero.